# S3 replication status FAILED

Tags: amazon-s3, replication, distributed

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr-status.html mentions:

> replication-status header with one of the following values for the
>   object's replication status: PENDING, COMPLETED, or FAILED.

What are the cases where FAILED might occur?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr-troubleshoot.html lists a bunch of cases. Aside from those cases is the only other case where the status might be failed when the other region is down?

UPDATE: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication-and-other-bucket-configs.html

Comment: Here's an updated URL to the list of cases for why FAILED might occur: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-replication/

For me, the problem was that the last item on that troubleshooting list: source bucket allowed public access and the destination bucket didn't. Those have to match for replication to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those should essentially be the only reasons.

`FAILED` should not occur even if the other region has an outage.  In that case, the status should stick at `PENDING` and later go to `COMPLETED`, if your configuration is all correct, based on this:

> `FAILED` is a terminal state that occurs only due to permission failures or misconfiguration (such as recreation of the destination bucket without versioning). It will not occur for transient issues.
>
> https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=617951